# When run the application its show the message installation failed in Xcode 7.2 OS10.10.5

Tags: ios, failed-installation, xcode7.2

When run the application its show the message installation failed in Xcode 7.2 OS10.10.5

Please help someone.

[image]

Comment: are you tried in simulator

Comment: yes in the simulator

Comment: clear the derived data and reset your simulator and try once

Comment: additional see this also https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7338

Comment: Clear the derived data reset the simulator, also reinstalled xcode. Still having the same error.

Comment: After removing the resources folder now its done.